# CLOCKS_PER_SEC undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-12.04

This is part of my program;

```
double get_cpu_time(){
 return (double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

But I get following error ;

> In function ‘get_cpu_time’: timertest.c:13:30: error: ‘CLOCKS_PER_SEC’
>   undeclared (first use in this function)

The header files that I have included are;

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<math.h>
 #include <sys/time.h>
```

Operating system is Ubuntu12.04 (installed just now ).

Why it is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include

```
<time.h>
```

instead of

```
<sys/time.h>
```

as per the manpage

```
man 3 clock
```

Comment: I have included <time.h>. It's still showing warning.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include [`<time.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html) instead of `<sys/time.h>`.